# Conda build creates empty package

Tags: python, conda, setuptools, conda-build

I am using conda-build version 3.11.0 and conda 4.9.2 and python 3.6.5.

I am running `conda build .` on our project, only to see the following output:

```
WARNING:conda_build.build:No files or script found for output ourtool
WARNING conda_build:bundle_conda(902): No files or script found for output ourtool
number of files: 0
```

Forgive me for not posting the full log. I can put more if needed, but I have to re-type the documents by hand as my development machine is restricted on network access.

In the built .tar.bz2, the structure is as follows:

```
/info
---files (EMPTY!)
---git
---index.json
---paths.json (EMPTY!)
---hash_input.json
---about.json
---/recipe
-------meta.yaml
-------bld.bat
-------MANIFEST.in
-------setup.py
-------.gitlab-ci.yml
-------requirements.txt
-------README.md
-------conda_build_config.yaml
-------/ourtool
---------__init__.py
---------mypythonfile.py
---------otherpythonfile.py
---------miscsettings.py
```

When I try to install the package with conda install, I get the following output:

```
Preparing Transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
```

**But the folder in site-packages is EMPTY!!**

The structure of the project is:

```
meta.yaml
bld.bat
MANIFEST.in
setup.py
.gitlab-ci.yml
requirements.txt
README.md
conda_build_config.yaml
/ourtool
--__init__.py
--mypythonfile.py
--otherpythonfile.py
--miscsettings.py
```

meta.yaml

```
{% set data = load_setup_py_data() %}

package:
   name: ourtool
   version: {{ data.get('version') }}

source:
    - path: ./ourtool
      folder: ourtool
    - path: ./setup.py
    - path: ./MANIFEST.in
    - path: ./README.md

build:
   number: 0
   entrypoints:
    - run_ourtool = ourtool.our_tool_main:main

requirements:
   build:
       - python {{python}}
       - setuptools
       - psutil
       - requests
       - ourinternalticketingtool
       - pandas
       - openpyxl
       - pyqt>5
       - lxml
   run:
       - python {{python}}
       - psutil
       - requests
       - ourinternalticketingtool
       - pandas
       - openpyxl
       - pyqt>5
       - lxml
```

setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name='ourtool',
    version='1.0.0',
    author='Me',
    url="https://ourinternalrepo.com/ourtool",
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[
        "psutil",
        "requests",
        "ourinternalticketingtool",
        "pandas",
        "openpyxl",
        "PyQt5",
        "lxml"
])
```

build.bat:

```
"%PYTHON%" setup.py install
if errorlevel 1 exit 1
```

conda_build_config.yaml:

```
python:
   -3.6
```

MANIFEST.in

```
include *.md
include requirements.txt
```

requirements.txt

`.`